# javascript jquery css event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseevent, event-listener

I'm reading JavaScript and JQuery by Jon Ducket and he makes it pretty clear that using HTML event handlers is bad practice (p. 250).

In my sample project I'm just trying to change the color of a few divs based on mouseover, mouse out, and click.

My friend says I should just do this using CSS, but I used jQuery.  Are CSS methods included in the category of HTML event handlers?

Would a scale of worst to best practice look like this: 
Worst > HTML event handler > CSS hover events > DOM event handlers > Level 2 DOM event listeners > Best

Should I just use CSS for the mouse events or is JQuery better practice?

Here's the HTML:

```
      <div>
          <br>
        <div class="myspecial" id="optionADiv">A</div>
        <div class="myspecial" id="optionBDiv">B</div>
        <div class="myspecial" id="optionCDiv">C</div>
        <div class="myspecial" id="optionDDiv">D</div>
      </div>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
$("#optionADiv").mouseover(function() {
    $("#optionADiv").addClass("highlight");
});

$("#optionADiv").mouseout(function() {
    $("#optionADiv").removeClass("highlight");
});

$("#optionBDiv").mouseover(function() {
    $("#optionBDiv").addClass("highlight");
});

$("#optionBDiv").mouseout(function() {
    $("#optionBDiv").removeClass("highlight");
});

$("#optionCDiv").mouseover(function() {
    $("#optionCDiv").addClass("highlight");
});

$("#optionCDiv").mouseout(function() {
    $("#optionCDiv").removeClass("highlight");
});

$("#optionDDiv").mouseover(function() {
    $("#optionDDiv").addClass("highlight");
});

$("#optionDDiv").mouseout(function() {
    $("#optionDDiv").removeClass("highlight");
});
```

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
    .myspecial {
        padding: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        border: 10px solid #c40909;
        display: inline-block;
        }

    .highlight {
        background-color: #c40909;
        }

    .clicked {
        background-color: #a22b2b;
        }
```

Comment: Do the `:hover` thing using CSS. Do the `click` think using JS.

Comment: Come on, it's a kindergarten of CSS. Read the basics.

Comment: I've read a lot, but when multiple ways are presented to do the same task, it's not always clear to me which method is considered the "best practice".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the :hover thing using CSS. Do the click think using JS.

Since you already use classes:

```
$(".myspecial").hover(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

will do it instead of all the jQuery code you used.
In CSS it's simple as:

```
.myspecial:hover{
   /* your styles here */
}
```

For the click do (in jQuery) like:

```
$(".myspecial").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

```
/* CSS: clicked class added by jQuery on click */
.clicked{
   /* your clicked styles here */
}
```

Note that the jQuery `.hover()` Method is a shorthand for both: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and you can also use it like:

```
$(".myspecial").hover(function(){
   // mouseenter stuff here
}, function(){
   // mouseleave stuff here
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  So in your opinion, hover events should be done with CSS and click events through JS?  That makes sense.  I also need to learn more about writing jquery functions.  You really compressed the code.  That's amazing!  Thanks again!

Comment: @redrobotx it all depends, if you want to simply change on css's `:hover` some colors etc and CSS is ok, otherwise if you need to do more complicated stuff like changing text, delegating later events etc etc than you need to use JS.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  At this time, I'm not doing much else, so I can see why using CSS would make more sense.